TypeScript Error in Svelte: Type Not Assignable for Conditional Component Rendering
I'm working on a SvelteKit project where I'm trying to create a console-like interface. Each line in the console can either be a prompt component for user input or a log component for displaying messages.
type def:
export type Prompt = [typeof PromptComponent, {
    onTextInput: (arg0: Event) => void;
    onKeyDown: (arg0: KeyboardEvent) => void;
    setInputRef: (ref: HTMLTextAreaElement | null) => void;
}];
export type Log = [typeof LogComponent, {
    str: string;
}];

export type ConsoleLine = Prompt | Log;

I create the components like this:
const newPrompt = () => {
    const newComponent: Prompt = [
        PromptComponent,
        {
            onTextInput: onTextInput,
            onKeyDown: onKeyDown,
            setInputRef: setInputRef
        }
    ];
    lines = [...lines, newComponent];
};

const newLog = (str: string) => {
    if (!str.length) return;
    const newComponent: Log = [
        LogComponent,
        {
            str: str
        }
    ];
    lines = [...lines, newComponent];
};

rendering:
{#each lines as line}
    <svelte:component this={line[0]} {...line[1]} />
{/each}

I'm getting the following TypeScript error:

Type '{ onTextInput: (arg0: Event) => void; onKeyDown: (arg0:
KeyboardEvent) => void; setInputRef: (ref: HTMLTextAreaElement | null)
=> void; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type '({ onTextInput: any; onKeyDown: any; setInputRef: any; } & { str: any; }) | undefined'.

TypeScript doesn't seem to understand that an element can't be of type Prompt and Log at the same time. How can I resolve this error in a clean and production-ready manner ?

I don't know if there is a good way of modelling internal relationships on the items - the array seems to make that impossible. On the level of one of the items, a relationship can be established using generics, so I would try to enforce correctness there and just ignore the error when rendering the items.
The relationship could be enforced like this:
import type { ComponentType, ComponentProps, SvelteComponentTyped } from 'svelte';

export type ComponentAndProps<T extends ComponentType<SvelteComponentTyped>> =
    [T, ComponentProps<InstanceType<T>>];

export type ConsoleLine =
    | ComponentAndProps<typeof PromptComponent>
    | ComponentAndProps<typeof LogComponent>;

To ignore type errors in the template you probably need to use a type assertion in the script (e.g. using a utility function that returns its argument as any).

Types in Svelte 5 as of now:
import type { Component, ComponentProps } from 'svelte';

export type ComponentAndProps<T extends Component<any>> =
    [T, ComponentProps<T>];

export type ConsoleLine =
    | ComponentAndProps<typeof PromptComponent>
    | ComponentAndProps<typeof LogComponent>;

In Svelte 5 you also can do the as any assertion directly in the template.

I'm adding the solution here for the documentation.
export const returnAsAny = (arg: any): any => {
    return arg;
}

No more type error.
{#each returnAsAny(lines) as line}
    <svelte:component this={line[0]} {...line[1]} />
{/each}

